# Ошибка при установке демо версии Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

На шаге 6 Установка продукта выдает ошибку:

```
Внимание! На данном шаге произошла ошибка установки продукта.

Повторите установку текущего шага. В случае повторения ошибки пропустите шаг.Пожалуйста, авторизуйтесь: Логин: Пароль:  Запомнить меня на этом компьютере Забыли свой пароль? try{document.form_auth.USER_LOGIN.focus();}catch(e){}
```

Отправляемые данные через POST на этом шаге:

```
CurrentStepID: create_modules
__wiz_agree_license: Y
__wiz_dbType: mysql
__wiz_lic_key_variant: 
__wiz_user_name: 
__wiz_user_surname: 
__wiz_email: 
__wiz_utf8: Y
__wiz_host: localhost
__wiz_create_user: N
__wiz_user: root
__wiz_password: 
__wiz_create_database: N
__wiz_database: sitemanager
__wiz_create_database_type: 
__wiz_root_user: 
__wiz_root_password: 
__wiz_file_access_perms: 0644
__wiz_folder_access_perms: 0755
__wiz_nextStep: b24connector
__wiz_nextStepStage: utf8
```

То есть по сути выдает страницу авторизации ответом на этот запрос. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Неизвестно из-за чего была, пришлось ставить через Docker

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте файл .access.php и замените в нем текст:

```
<?
$PERM["/"]["*"]="R";
?>
```

Comment: 1. пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] 2. переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык